# how can js(jquery) run before image is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, dom

I want to change image url when the images are not loaded in html DOM. (before browser loads image)

Can js do this?

demo code:

```
...
<body>
   <img src="old src"> <!-- this **HTML** is loaded from a database and i want to change this src using javascript-->
</body>
....
```

I tried

```
$(function(){$(img).attr('src','new src');}); //it is can work ,but the brower will load old image first. then the js will run.
```

Beacause the **HTML** is loaded from a database, I have no idea how to operate html string in server code(java). so i want use js to change image src.

**EDIT:**

for example:

old src = "old domain/test.jpg" i want to change it to "right domian2(CDN)/test_width_height.jpg"

the old src  is not in server, so the brower will get 404 error from server first.
   when the src change to new src, then brower will reload image from new src, then the correct image will display.

i do not want the borwer 404 error first, i just want the browser to load the right image from the right address.

Comment: change `src` to "" in HTML.

Comment: @Ravi beacause the image is loaded from a database, I have no idea how to operate html string in server code(java). so i want use js to change image src.

Comment: @martynas that is not i want, i want change the src before brower loaded image.

Comment: try onload function on window or the body

Comment: @SimranjeetSingh i also can get 404 frist,then the js run

Answer (score 1):

If you have any problem in loading the image, you can alternatively set the other image in `onError`

```
<img src="old domain/test.jpg" alt="Not Available"
 onError="this.src='right domian2(CDN)/test_width_height.jpg';" />
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution the same as my demo. that will got 404 fisrt.and i can not operate the html src in java code（server）

Comment: The possibility of running an infinite loop is present here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the image **complete** property to determine wheather the image is loaded or not . If not you can modify the src of the img tag as required.

Please have look at the below url ,

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_complete.asp

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning do not add any url to the image tag. add them at certain condition like on pageload as

```
// define the function that assign the image url
function assignImageSrc(){ 
    $('#imageID').prop('src','add your url here');
}
```

call it as

```
<form onload="assignImageSrc()" >
//
</form>
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: beacause the borswer will get old image that the function of assignImageSrc is not run ,chrome will print 404 first then will change iamge src. i just do not want got 404.html display speed will slow when that are a lot of images.

Comment: As far as i know, if the **src** of the image is defined you can not restrict to load from the server. You have to remove value of **src** tag at the time of definition . It must empty string to load after the javascript function calls ..

Comment: alright, looks like i can't solve it using js. although the result is correct, it doesn't look right. this might affect the browers operation.